# Groovy expression to filter strings randomly with specified probability

Tags: groovy

The input is a random string (not uniformly distributed).

I need a one-liner groovy expression that, based on the input, with specified probability, returns me true or false.

For an input of int value i would use `intValue % 100 < p` where `p` is desired probability percentage.

How do I do this for a string? I am thinking of using a hash function, e.g. `md5()` to make my input more uniform. But the output of string.md5() in groovy is still a string, so what can I do with it?

I thought of comparing last character, e.g. `['0','1'].contains(myString.md5()[31])` but it doesn't allow for decimal granularity and is quite cumbersome to update.

Answer (score 0):

This works just right:

```
new BigInteger(myString.md5(), 16) % 100 < p
```

Comment: Are you expecting that to return true for `p%` of all values for `myString`?

Comment: assuming that md5 is uniform, yes